# how to change android app's look at runtime

Tags: android, colors, android-xml, android-theme

I have defined colors in colors.xml like below

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#5D4037</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#4E342E</color>
    <color name="accent">#FF3D00</color>
</resources>
```

I have also defined themes in styles.xml, like below

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Also, at many places in code, I have used these colors to set it for text, etc.
Now I want to give option to users to change the colors. I read that I can't change colors specified in colors.xml. Also, even if I change the `theme`, the color referenced can't be changed. So specifying more themes (with hard-coded colors) could be an option, but in that case what will happen to elements which has got color dynamically? Also, user cannot select *any* color but has to use only the colors specified by me in themes.

Am I missing something obvious? How this can be done?

Comment: i dont think you can change the style programmatically you need to change to each element,

Comment: make a spinner, declare these fields(primary,primary_dark,accent) and call colors on click.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change values in your resource files at runtime.

If you want to allow your users to customize the colors in your app, you will need to store an manage those colors yourself, perhaps using resource files to provide defaults or to store the options that users can select from.